# How do I install a patch file?

Tags: 7, drush

I was trying to google the method to install a patch file, but the results keep returning as "issues encountered while patching", which isn't what I am looking for.

I was wondering how to use drush to install a patch file?

More specifically, I'm currently encountering a Drupal for Facebook module [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1715310), about the q variable.

One of the answers suggests installing a patch file. How do i install this patch file from the command line?

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23347/how-do-i-apply-a-patch-file)..

Comment: i am aware of that question. But there still isn't any direct answer on how to apply a patch file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The instructions on how to apply a patch are given, for that module, on http://drupal.org/project/fb/git-instructions.

First off, git patches can be applied to a git repository you need to locally clone, which means you need to execute the following command:

```
git clone --recursive --branch master http://git.drupal.org/project/fb.git
```

Then you copy the patch in the fb directory created from the previous command, and execute the following one:

```
cd fb
git apply -v fb_stream.admin_.inc_.patch
```

Once the patch is applied, you delete it.

```
rm  fb_stream.admin_.inc_.patch
```

This assume the patch is applied to the development snapshot. If this is not the case, then somebody needs to provide a patch for the development snapshot.

Anyway, the patch doesn't apply. If you try applying it, you will get the following error:

> Checking patch Users/johnrobens/Downloads/fb/fb_stream.admin.inc...
>   error: Users/johnrobens/Downloads/fb/fb_stream.admin.inc: No such file or directory

You need to change the patch to the following one, to avoid that error.

```
--- fb_stream.admin.inc
+++ fb_stream.admin.inc
@@ -1,5 +1,6 @@
 <?php

+
 /**
  * Form callback for general settings.
  */
@@ -19,7 +20,8 @@
             '%user_name' => $from['name'],
             '%token' => $token,
           )));
-    } catch (Exception $e) {
+    }
+    catch (Exception $e) {
       fb_log_exception($e, t('Unable to query graph with fb_stream token.'));
       drupal_set_message(t('There was an error using the current access token, %token.  Consider generating a new token.', array(
             '%token' => $token,
@@ -29,7 +31,7 @@

   if (!empty($_REQUEST['code']) && empty($_POST)) {
     // Send user to this URL after token is generated.
-    $redirect_uri = url(request_path(), array(
+    $redirect_uri = url($_REQUEST['q'], array(
       'absolute' => TRUE,
       'query' => array(
         'client_id' => $_REQUEST['client_id'],
@@ -59,7 +61,7 @@
   );
   foreach (fb_get_all_apps() as $fb_app) {
     // Send user to this URL after token is generated.
-    $redirect_uri = url(request_path(), array(
+    $redirect_uri = url($_REQUEST['q'], array(
       'absolute' => TRUE,
       'query' => array(
         'client_id' => $fb_app->id,
@@ -92,7 +94,7 @@
       'client_id' => $app_id,
       'client_secret' => $fb_app->secret,
       'code' => $code,
-      'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
+                  'redirect_uri' =>$redirect_uri,
     ),
       ));
   $http = drupal_http_request($path);
```

Even if you do that, you would get the error, "patch doesn't apply." I tried applying it to the development snapshot 7.x-3.x (the master branch for git).

Comment: is anything supposed to show up after "git apply -v [patchname.patch] ?

Comment: As far as I recall, `git apply` doesn't shown any message when it successfully applies the patch.

Answer (score 1):

Here's really good explanation of [applying patches](http://drupal.org/patch/apply) with git. If you haven't got git installed there's some links to instructions for various different platforms [here](http://drupal.org/node/1010894).

Beyond that, make sure you are patching the correct version of the code otherwise you may get errors when applying the patch.

Some more general info on git can be found in the [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book) book.

Comment: Also, give the drush issue queue commands a try!  http://drupal.org/project/drush_iq

Comment: That's interesting, hadn't come across that before!

Comment: @splatio how can you apply a patch to a module from a patch folder to the contrib module

Answer (score 0):

Without details regarding your environment, patching details would be very difficult to give and would likely not be appropriate for drupal.stackexchange.com.  Drupal has a bit of documentation though that my lead you in the right direction.

http://drupal.org/patch/apply

In the simplest form using patch `patch -p1 < path/file.patch` or if you use git `git apply path/file.patch`

Comment: i did try both; using git apply did not change anything. Using patch -p1< path/file.patch returns error, something about HUNK failing.

Comment: @Citricguy so if i place the patch in a patch file first to patch the module from the patch file is it  patch -p1 < path/file.patch